# Java regex for replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

What is the regex expression for replace all the A char with A1, B->B1, C->C1, D->D1 and E->E1 string?

```
//AND(A<>B,C>D)?GREEN(E-E)

String expr ="AND(A<>B,C>D)?GREEN(E-E)";
String regex="";
expr.replaceAll(regex, "N1");
System.out.println(expr);
```

The result may be:

```
AND(A1<>B1,C1>D1)?GREEN(E1-E1)
```

Thank you

Comment: Now it's ok thanks

Comment: `_` has no special meaning in regex, maybe you are confusing it with SQL's replace syntax?

Comment: @1blustone maybe he wrote anything because he says he does not what to write ^^

Comment: @michele, after your edit the question is clear, have just provided an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\b([A-E])\b
```

With the replacement string `$11`

Bear in mind that in java you have to escape backslasher, so you have to use:

```
String expr = "AND(A<>B,C>D)?GREEN(E-E)";
expr = expr.replaceAll("\\b([A-E])\\b", "$11");
System.out.println(expr);
```

**[Java demo](https://ideone.com/FZoDC7)**

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dao6qM/3)**

[image]

Update: following your comment, if you want to extend the regex to all letters, then replace `[A-E]` to `[A-Z]`.

Comment: it s not working with this expression AND(J<>Q,N-(N*10/100)>O) ...why?

Comment: @michele because you said A, B, C, D and E. If you want to replace all letters, then change `A-E` to `A-Z`